# C# - How to get variables from a different method?

Tags: c#, random

I need too make an addition of 2 random numbers, stored in an int variable and in a different method. What is the easiest and simplest way to do it please?

Thanks!

```
public void generateNumbers()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 11);
            int randomNumber2 = rand.Next(1, 11);
            Console.WriteLine("Number1: " + randomNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Number2: " + randomNumber2);
        }

        public int findSum()
        {
            //sum = randomNumber + randomNumber2 //gets sum from the method generateNumbers()
            return sum;
        }
```

Comment: Make `randomNumber` and `randomNumber2` class level variables

Comment: Change their scope to a more general one or pass them as parameters.

Comment: Read a programming tutorial or see almost any working applications code (however simple). Closure is very much programming 101, not an issue you researched, trialled, looked again for duplicate issues and still unable to fix - but that is **exactly** what you need to do **before** you ask here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make them instance variables of the class containing the two methods. This way, they are accessible to all the methods of the class, and it's value is preserved between the calls to those methods.

```
class ContainingClass
{
    int randomNumber;
    int randomNumber2;

    public void generateNumbers()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 11);
        randomNumber2 = rand.Next(1, 11);
        Console.WriteLine("Number1: " + randomNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Number2: " + randomNumber2);
    }

    public int findSum()
    {
        return randomNumber + randomNumber2; //gets sum from the method generateNumbers()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did learn how int works now in methods and outside :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Tuple` to pass the two values between the methods, as the following (C~ 6) code shows:

```
public Tuple<int, int> GenerateNumbers()
{
    var rand = new Random();
    return Tuple.Create(rand.Next(1, 11), rand.Next(1, 11));
}

public int FindSum(Tuple<int, int> numbers) => numbers.Item1 + numbers.Item2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Processor proc = new Processor();
            proc.generateNumbers();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the processor class
using System;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Processor
    {
        public void generateNumbers()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            AddModel addModel = findSum(rand);
            Console.WriteLine("Number1: " + addModel.Left);
            Console.WriteLine("Number2: " + addModel.Right);
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + addModel.Sum);
        }

        private AddModel findSum(Random rand)
        {
            AddModel addModel = new AddModel();
            addModel.Left = rand.Next(1, 11);
            addModel.Right = rand.Next(1, 11);
            addModel.Sum = addModel.Left + addModel.Right;
            return addModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the add model class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class AddModel
    {
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Right { get; set; }
        public int Sum { get; set; }
    }
}
```